# how to generate Google map with bounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I have a question. Now I generate my map with this function:

```
function mapStart() {
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(c1, c2);
var MapOption = {
zoom: 6,
center: center,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapka"), MapOption);
```

My question is - how I can generate this map without 'center' type, but with bounds?
For example:
New map with bounds:

```
NorthEast = 51;
NorthWest = 55;
SouthEast = 45;
SouthWest = 44;
```

[this is just a random numbers]

how I can do this?

Greetings!

EDIT#
This is my new code

```
        var test1 = "(" + nelat + ", " + nelng + ")";
        var test2 = "(" + swlat + ", " + swlng + ")";
        //alert(test1); => (50.355089589491605, 25.734125341796926)
        //alert(test2); => (49.467221440947704, 23.806024755859426)
        var newbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(test1, test2);

        function mapaStart() {
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(c1, c2);
            var MapOption = {
                zoom: 6,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapka"), MapOption);
            map.fitBounds(newbounds);
```

But this code doesn't work properly. When i press ctrl+shift+j, I get this error:

> Error: a.lat is not a function Source:
>
> http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/pl_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/9/8/main.js

how to solve this problem?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) from your numbers
2. call the [Map.fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) method

`map.fitBounds(bounds);`

Comment: I added my new code into first post. Bounds doesn't set properly.

Comment: please review the documentation on LatLngBounds.  It takes two LatLng objects as arguments, you are passing in strings.

Comment: oh, thanks! now i have 2 lanlng objects, fitBounds almost work nice. but there is another problem - when i refresh page with method fitBounds and new bounds, zoom level is smaller than original by -1. How i can solve it? I tried with
var zoom1 = map.getZoom(); 
map.setZoom(zoom1 + 1);
after method fitBounds, but this doesn't work, map is grey.